# How can I use Vash and Razor at the same time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, vash

I'm developing an application with ASP.NET MVC, in my view I'm using Razor as a template engine for my server side code. I was searching for a template engine for my client side code and I found [Vash](https://github.com/kirbysayshi/vash). as you probably know Vash has a pretty clean syntax like Razor.

I am just curious if it is possible to use both of them in the same view file?

Comment: I haven't use Vash (or even heard of it until this question) but given that it uses Razor-like syntax (specifically the `@`) what you'd probably have to do is double-`@` your Vash code so Razor doesn't try to interpret it. In theory Razor should strip off the extra `@` and allow the client-side templating code to take over.